# How to deal with duplicate fields in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do some analysis on data I have scraped from a forum. This is the first time I'm doing something like this so it's possible that my method is wrong from the start but here is what I have at the moment.

I have scraped 17k discussions, each of which contains a certain number of posts (for a total of 78k post). I have stored everything in a dataframe with 6 columns. Each row corresponds to a post, and the columns are respectively:

```
'thread_id', 'thread_length', 'thread_title', 'post_number', 'post content' ,'poster'
```

As you can see the values that pertain to the thread (so title, id, and length) are repeated a lot of times: for example if a thread has 30 posts, its id, length and title will be repeated 30 times.

My problem is: how can I plot an histogram of the thread lengths? I probably should only pick length values that have a different thread id value, but I can't figure out how to do it. Also I guess there has to be a 'cleaner' way to organize this dataframe, so I'm open to any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns look fine to me. You can use:

```
df.drop_duplicates('thread_id').thread_length.plot.hist()
```

- `drop_duplicates` identifies duplicates by considering the `thread_id` column only, keeping the first occurrence (by default).
- I then take the `thread_length` column,
- which gives you a `Series` that you can `plot` with method `hist` to get a histogram.

Comment: @jdehesa I guess you're right! Removed the value counting step.

Comment: Thanks my dude, that's what I was looking for.